# How to pass the full path of a file as an argument to a new instance of Powershell?

Tags: powershell

This is the code of my script that calls another script:

```
$LocalFolder = "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Banana Productions"
$RenderClient = "$LocalFolder\Render\Modelo 02\Cliente 02"
$CutFolder = "$RenderClient\Cortar"
$FFMpegScript = "$CutFolder\ffmpeg crop.ps1" 

gci "$RenderClient\Cortar" *.mp4 -File -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
$FilePath = $_.FullName
start PowerShell "-NoExit", "-File", "`"$FFMpegScript`"", "$FilePath"
Write-Host $FilePath
}
```

The issue is that I am not able to pass the argument with the value of `$_.FullName` to the new instance, I get an error message in the new instance with the message:

```
Cannot process argument because the value of argument "name" is not valid
```

This is all that's in the script I'm calling:

```
param($args)

Write-Host $args[0]

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to continue"
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to a long-standing bug in [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) - see [GitHub issue #5576](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5576) - it is best to pass a *single* string argument to the (positionally implied) `-ArgumentList` parameter, which allows you to control the process command line explicitly:

The following uses an expandable [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) for syntactic convenience:

```
Get-ChildItem "$RenderClient\Cortar" -Filter *.mp4 -File -Recurse |
  ForEach-Object {
    $FilePath = $_.FullName
    Start-Process PowerShell @"
-NoExit -File "$FFMpegScript" "$FilePath"
"@ # Note: This must be at the very start of the line.
  }
```

---

Additionally, do *not* use the [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) as a *custom* variable.

In fact, if you want your script to receive *positional* arguments only, there is *no* need for a formal `param(...)` declaration - just use the array-valued `$args` variable as-is:

```
# Without a param(...) declaration, $args *implicitly* contains
# any arguments passed, as an array.

$args[0] # output the 1st argument passed.

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to continue"
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! Dude thank you so much for your help and patience to explain, you solved a huge headache I was having.